# How to increase the length of the arrows/increase space in schemes in chemfig?

Tags: chemfig

I have a reaction scheme as shown in figure below:

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
A \arrow(a--b){->[*{0}$\mathrm{-HO}$][*{0}$\mathrm{+O_{2}}$]}[-90] B
\arrow(@b--c){->[][]} C
% \subscheme{\arrow{->}\lewis{1.,R}}%
\arrow(@b--d){<=>[][*{0}$\mathrm{+O_{2}}$]}[-90] D
\arrow(@d--f){} F
\arrow(@d--f){->[$\mathrm{-\lewis{1.,HO}}$][]}
\arrow(@b--@f){->[$\mathrm{+O_{2}}$][$\mathrm{-\lewis{1.,HO}}$]}
\arrow(@d--e){<=>[][]}[-90] E
\arrow(@e--g){->[$\mathrm{-\lewis{3.,OH}}$][]} G
\arrow(@e--@f){->[$\mathrm{-\lewis{1.,HO}}$][]}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

However the area around product 'F' appears to be cramped. To fix this I add some space as shown in figure:

[image]

**MWE after adding space**

```
\\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
A \arrow(a--b){->[*{0}$\mathrm{-HO}$][*{0}$\mathrm{+O_{2}}$]}[-90] B
\arrow(@b--c){->[][]} C
% \subscheme{\arrow{->}\lewis{1.,R}}%
\arrow(@b--d){<=>[][*{0}$\mathrm{+O_{2}}$]}[-90] D
\arrow(@d--f){} \hspace{3em} F
\arrow(@d--f){->[$\mathrm{-\lewis{1.,HO}}$][]}
\arrow(@b--@f){->[$\mathrm{+O_{2}}$][$\mathrm{-\lewis{1.,HO}}$]} \hspace{7em}
\arrow(@d--e){<=>[][]}[-90] E
\arrow(@e--g){->[$\mathrm{-\lewis{3.,OH}}$][]} G
\arrow(@e--@f){->[$\mathrm{-\lewis{1.,HO}}$][]}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

Now, two problems exists:

1. The length of the arrow from 'D' to 'F' does not increase.
2. The arrows are not exactly aligned with 'F'

***How to fix the above two issues with schemes in chemfig?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The length of an arrow can be set by adding a multiplier after the angle:

```
\arrow(@d--f){}[0, 2] F
```

where the `2` indicates that the arrow has twice the standard length. Note also that you should replace `f` by `@f` in the next line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

    \schemestart
    A \arrow(a--b){->[*{0}$\mathrm{-HO}$][*{0}$\mathrm{+O_{2}}$]}[-90] B
    \arrow(@b--c){->[][]} C
    % \subscheme{\arrow{->}\lewis{1.,R}}%
    \arrow(@b--d){<=>[][*{0}$\mathrm{+O_{2}}$]}[-90] D
    \arrow(@d--f){}[0, 2] F
    \arrow(@d--@f){->[$\mathrm{-\lewis{1.,HO}}$][]}
    \arrow(@b--@f){->[$\mathrm{+O_{2}}$][$\mathrm{-\lewis{1.,HO}}$]}
    \arrow(@d--e){<=>[][]}[-90] E
    \arrow(@e--g){->[$\mathrm{-\lewis{3.,OH}}$][]} G
    \arrow(@e--@f){->[$\mathrm{-\lewis{1.,HO}}$][]}
    \schemestop

\end{document}
```