# Vertical chemical reactions

Tags: chemistry, mhchem

Is there any way to write chemical reactions with vertical branching as done in the following image? [image]

Comment: I suggest like a starting point to see these links, for example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/475329/chemfig-double-harpoon-curved-arrow-in-reaction-rate-constants, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448825/chemfig-double-harpoon-arched-in-out-arrow-in-reaction, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405405/how-to-increase-the-length-of-the-arrows-increase-space-in-schemes-in-chemfig

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I was not aware of chemfig. However when I simply copy the examples in the answers you provided I get `Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \CF@arrow@start@node`

Comment: Thus we not can see to solve the problem. If you put a minimal complete compilable code (MWE) all users can provide to solve the problem: if it is possibile. All the best.